# "verschiedene" vs. "die unterschiedliche"

Tags: word-choice, definite-article

A corrector corrrected my

> Grafische Darstellungen der Programme laufen Gefahr unterschiedlicher Interpretationen bei **verschiedenen** Betrachtern.

zu

> Grafische Darstellungen der Programme laufen Gefahr unterschiedlicher Interpretationen bei **den unterschiedlichen** Betrachtern.

Why? Which rules force us to

- change the adjective and
- use the definite article?

Comment: This specific question cannot be answered without more context. Or would you like us to guess? I would have corrected even more, BTW.

Comment: @tofro I've just added a bit more context. Of course, I cannot copy/paste the whole text, but if you want me to be more specific, you should tell me which part you'd need to have more information about.

Answer (score 3):

*Grafische Darstellungen laufen Gefahr unterschiedlicher Interpretationen bei verschiedenen Betrachtern.*

This sentence is wrong for a different reason. *Gefahr laufen* takes an action, not a genitive object. You may either use an object clause or an infinitive clause. For simple actions, a *zu-Infinitiv* suffices:

> Grafische Darstellungen **laufen Gefahr**, dass sie unterschiedliche Interpretationen bei verschiedenen Betrachtern **hervorrufen**.
>
> Grafische Darstellungen **laufen Gefahr**, unterschiedliche Interpretationen bei verschiedenen Betrachtern **hervorzurufen**.
>
> Grafische Darstellungen **laufen Gefahr zu verwirren**.

If you don't like this, use **bergen die Gefahr**. That one can take either an action or a genitive object:

> Grafische Darstellungen **bergen die Gefahr** unterschiedlicher Interpretationen bei verschiedenen Betrachtern.

---

About *verschiedener* vs. *unterschiedlicher*, I think your teacher made a hypercorrection. All four variants (verschiedenen, unterschiedlichen, with/without article) cover the intended meaning in this sentence, it's just a matter of style which one you use.

I personally would settle for:

> Grafische Darstellungen bergen die Gefahr unterschiedlicher Interpretationen **durch** unterschiedliche Betrachter.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why did my corrector use the definite article?

Comment: If you add the definite article, you add a finger pointing at the *unterschiedlichen Betrachter*. It's just a nuance in meaning. It's okay both with and without the article.

Comment: This is not 100% clear from @Janka 's excellent answer, but the corrected sentence is also wrong for the same reason - the genitive object is still there. This is a great site to see words in context: https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=laufen+gefahr

Comment: @Janka: Für mich ist es so: _unterschiedlich_ = sich unterscheidend, voneinander verschieden; _verschieden_ (u.a. auch) eine Art indefiniter Artikel mit ähnlicher Bedeutung wie '_mehrere_' oder '_einzelne_'. Man könnte vielleicht auch sagen: _Mit/Bei grafischen Darstellungen gibt es ein Problem: Sie könn(t)en von verschiedenen/einzelnen Betrachtern unterschiedlich interpretiert / aufgefasst werden._ - Nur als zusätzliche Möglichkeit, die anderen Vorschläge finde ich gut.

Comment: Wegen der Dopplung von 'unterschiedlich(er)' halte ich die Abwechslung durch 'verschiedene' sogar für besser.